# Android Studio 2.2 cannot find references for all kotlin files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

After updating to Android Studio 2.2, I keep getting the error "*Unresolved reference*" in **all** kotlin files.

The specific failing gradle task is:
`:app:compileStagingDebugKotlinAfterJava` (for a variant called `StagingDebug`)

The only solution I've found so far is to run `clean`. But I don't want to run this every time in do changes in my code. Any help?

Comment: Does 2.2.1 fix it for you? How did you set up Kotlin in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the kotlin plugin version in Android studio and the kotlin version that you are using(check build.gradle) are the same.

Comment: I'm using plugin 1.0.4 and importing kotlin 1.0.3, but I cannot update this last to 1.0.4 because of dependencies that still depend on version 1.0.3. But, as soon as these dependencies support 1.0.4, I'll do that and hope the bug is gone :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After updating AS please configure your project again like described below: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

Always choose `Stable` channel for `Kotlin` updates.

I don't think that `1.0.4` version is already in `stable` channel. Why? The latest version is compatible with the latest version of `IntelliJ IDEA`, so it may cause problems in the `Aandroid Studio` which does not follow `IDEA` versions.

Hope it will help

Comment: I'm using kotlin 1.0.3 and plugin 1.0.4. Are you talking about which one?

Comment: I'd talked about the second one. Kotlin and k-plugin should be the same, so if at that time 1.04 was in unsatble version you should keep with the older one, I mean 1.03.